# Checking the range of the date input from the date on the database

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a table named nca and  heres what it looks like with values :

```
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
| nca_id | nca_no  | issue_date | nca_amount | account_type | balance |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
|      1 | 14-0001 | 2015-01-08 |     200000 | ROP          |       0 |
|      2 | 14-0002 | 2015-01-08 |     400000 | ROP          |       0 |
|      3 | 14-0003 | 2015-02-02 |    1000000 | ROP          |       0 |
|      4 | 14-0004 | 2015-02-02 |     300000 | ROP          |       0 |
|      5 | 14-0001 | 2015-01-08 |     250000 | DBP-TRUST    |       0 |
|      6 | 14-0002 | 2015-01-08 |     400000 | DBP-TRUST    |       0 |
+--------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+
```

Now using this query it can display the SUM of the nca_amount base on the issue_date:

```
SELECT SUM(nca_amount) FROM nca WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND issue_date = '2015-02-02'
```

which gives a result of 1300000 since it adds all the amount that having a date of 2015-02-02 and just works fine if you set the date just on the query itself.

But I have scenario that I want to solve. I have an html form where the user could enter the date he want.

And if the user would type the date of 2015-02-23, I want this date input referring to the issue_date of 2015-02-02 from my table. What I want is if the date input is in the RANGE of the MONTH of the issue_date on the nca table, this would refer to the issue_date found on the nca table and display the sum. For example :

user input_date = '2015-02-23'    referring to issue_date = '2015-02-02'

as the inputted date is in the range of '2015-02-02' found on my nca table and then it can display the sum like on my query above. How can I do this query? Can any one help with this one? thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do something like `WHERE YEAR(issue_date) = YEAR('2015-02-02') AND MONTH(issue_date) = MONTH('2015-02-02')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match the month:

```
SELECT SUM(nca_amount)
FROM nca
WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND
      year(issue_date) = year('2015-02-02') and
      month(issue_date) = month('2015-02-02');
```

However, this doesn't allow the query to use an index on `issue_date`.  For that, you need to rephrase the query as:

```
SELECT SUM(nca_amount)
FROM nca
WHERE account_type = 'ROP' AND
      issue_date >= date(concat(left('2015-02-02', 7), '-01')) and
      issue_date <  date(concat(left('2015-02-02', 7), '-01')) + interval 1 month;
```

Comment: I like this answer because it addresses the indexing issue, however the second example returns null. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80124b/3/0)

Comment: @scrowler fixed. I think all 3 of us now need to share points for this answer

Comment: That works. But what if the inputted date is for example: '2015-02-01' and the issue_date on my table is '2015-02-02', this must not return the sum if the inputted date is before the issue_date on my table as the day of the inputted date is '01'and the issue_date is '02'. How can I do that ?

Comment: @Larcy: so basically you need to fetch all issue_date's that start with first of the month, to the selected date? Change `issue_date <  date(concat(left('2015-02-02', 7), '-01'))` to `issue_date <= '2015-02-02'`.